# How to check if facebook user likes a website page or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

I am looking for a method to check if a currently logged in user likes a particular website or not. I don't want this without asking permission from user through an application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check if a user `likes` a particular page unless they have their likes available to the public (as per the Facebook privacy settings). You cannot query a specific page for a list of user that like it unless you have particular rights with that page (and are logged in).

See the FB Graph API docs for more information: [Graph API](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQqwMoADAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fapi%2Fuser%2F&rct=j&q=facebook%20graph%20api&ei=9d0ETp3OM4TYiALQqaHWDQ&usg=AFQjCNGaMWOruOUGKxDnkkBCYJk5VW2quA&sig2=lg8aRuvusJKkOWpLhKXO3A&cad=rja)

Comment: can I check for current page ?

Comment: If you mean the current page the user is on, then the answer is no unless the user has that data publicly available. The pages I reference in my above post are the community/branding pages on Facebook itself. However, the same is true for the like button that can appear on any webpage.